# Claiming a tunnel when no matching cards are turned over

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

Could I claim a tunnel if there are no cards matching the color of the cards played to claim the Tunnel?

I want to claim a red tunnel of 4 cards. I have 4 red cards. Three top cards from the Train draw pile are turned face-up and there are no red cards or train cards there.

The rules state:

> When attempting to claim a Tunnel route, a player first lays down the number of cards required by the length of the route. Then the three top cards from the Train draw pile are turned face-up. For each card revealed whose color matches the color of the cards played to claim the Tunnel, an additional card of the same color (or a Locomotive) must now be played from his hand. Only then can the player successfully claim the Tunnel route.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can. There were zero cards revealed from the train draw pile which matched the colour of the cards used to claim the tunnel (red), so you must play zero extra red cards - and having done that trivial action, you claim the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw no red cards **OR locomotive** (wild) cards, you would not pay any extra cards, correct.